# Chrome add-on triggers Content Security Policy violation

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, github, google-chrome-extension

***Chrome add-on triggers Content Security Policy violation***

Recently, I have started developing a chrome add-on that will inject a button into [GitHub](http://github.com) user profiles. The add-on is designed to inject a [KeyBase](http://keybase.io) button on GitHub user profiles that correspond with KeyBase user profiles as shown in the image.

[image: KeyBase Button Example]

My main code is written in JavaScript, can be found at the following link:

https://gist.github.com/psgs/10516497

My manifest.json file is also as follows:

https://gist.github.com/psgs/10516524

When the code is run as part of the chrome add-on, the following error is spammed in the JavaScript console, and when pressed, the KeyBase button won't link the user to the user's KeyBase profile.

[image: JavaScript Console Error]

Any insight as to why these errors are occuring would be much appreciated!!

More information can also be found at the [GitHub Issues page for the KeyBase Button repository](https://github.com/psgs/KeybaseButton/issues).

Comment: Upgrade your Chrome browser and try again.

Comment: I'm currently running the latest dev channel build of Google Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to run your code and I couldn't reproduce errors from your screenshot. Basically button is injected ok, but when I press it I'm getting:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.keybase.io/psgs. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://github.com' is therefore not allowed access. psgs:1
>   AJAX Error  github-a1fec3e73d87f3550c635e371c8519308940f4b4.js:1

Here is what I think is happening:

- When button is clicked event is captured by GitHub javascript code and get converted to some kind of Ajax request.
- This request doesn't work because www.keybase.io doesn't allow requests from different origin.

You can try to add your our `click` handler to the button, which will stop event bubbling up to GitHub handler like this:

```
button
    .attr('href', 'https://www.keybase.io/' + username)
    .html('<span class="octicon octicon-key"></span>Keybase')
    .click(function() {window.location = 'https://www.keybase.io/' + username})
```

Anyway it's not quite clear what are you trying to achieve.